# Magento: Override only a part of a layout xml-File

Tags: magento, layout

I only want to change a part of the file checkout.xml (this file is in the core layout-folder).  I create my own extension and link to my own layout-xml-File in my config.xml.

```
<layout>

  <updates>
    <checkout>
     <file>mymodule_checkout.xml</file>
    </checkout>
  </updates>
</layout>
```

There are no problems, when i copy the whole file checkout.xml and save it as mymodule_checkout.xml. But I only want to override a little part of this big file between

```
<reference name="content">
```

and

```
</reference>
```

In this case, when i only write the parts that i needed, magento only read my file with this parts. So magento don't get the remaining parts of the original checkout.xml.

Is it possible to only change a part of a core layout xml-File without copying the whole file or change the core.

The Code of mymodule.xml looks like this:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">

<checkout_onepage_index translate="label">

    <reference name="content">
        <block type="checkout/onepage" name="checkout.onepage" template="checkout/onepage.phtml">
            <block type="checkout/onepage_login" name="checkout.onepage.login" as="login" template="checkout/onepage/login.phtml">
                <block type="page/html_wrapper" name="checkout.onepage.login.before" as="login_before" translate="label">
                    <label>Login/Registration Before</label>
                    <action method="setMayBeInvisible">
                        <value>1</value>
                    </action>
                </block>
                <block type="checkout/onepage_billing" name="checkout.onepage.billing" as="billing" template="checkout/onepage/billing.phtml"/>
                <block type="checkout/onepage_shipping" name="checkout.onepage.shipping" as="shipping" template="checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml"/>
            </block>
            <block type="checkout/onepage_shipping_method" name="checkout.onepage.shipping_method" as="shipping_method" template="checkout/onepage/shipping_method.phtml">
                <block type="checkout/onepage_shipping_method_available" name="checkout.onepage.shipping_method.available" as="available" template="checkout/onepage/shipping_method/available.phtml"/>
                <block type="checkout/onepage_shipping_method_additional" name="checkout.onepage.shipping_method.additional" as="additional" template="checkout/onepage/shipping_method/additional.phtml"/>
            </block>
            <block type="checkout/onepage_payment" name="checkout.onepage.payment" as="payment" template="checkout/onepage/payment.phtml">
                <block type="checkout/onepage_payment_methods" name="checkout.payment.methods" as="methods" template="checkout/onepage/payment/methods.phtml">
                    <action method="setMethodFormTemplate">
                        <method>purchaseorder</method>
                        <template>payment/form/purchaseorder.phtml</template>
                    </action>
                </block>
            </block>
            <block type="checkout/onepage_review" name="checkout.onepage.review" as="review" template="checkout/onepage/review.phtml"/>
        </block>
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_index>
</layout>
```

Thats the part I need. In this Case, magento take only this code not the remaining code of the core xml-file.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, yes. Magento combines all your layout files into one, including files from fallback themes. Whatever is still relevant after it's processed all your files is what is used to produce your layout and as long as your xml is formatted correctly you can override any section from any .xml file - i.e. just 'cause it's called page.xml doesn't mean you can't override it in foobarbaz.xml.

It's more than likely your problem lies with your XML, can you post the contents of `mymodule_checkout.xml` so I can figure out what you're trying to do and hopefully provide you with a working replacement?

Comment: I post the Code in my Question

Comment: Thanks for the update. The code you have posted seems fine, except for a close block in the wrong page. I don't know if this was the intention but your billing and shipping sections in the above code are assigned to the login page. Those two declarations, `checkout.onepage.billing` and `checkout.onepage.shipping` should come *after* the </block>.

Can you tell me exactly what is missing from the onepage checkout with your replaced code, in comparison to what is there with the default code? Perhaps you could also provide a URL to the page, for illustration? Thanks!

Comment: The billing and shipping block on this position as a child of the login-block was intended. Thats the changes I need. Everything else of the onepage checkout is missing. Magento gets only my code.

Comment: If I take the whole Code of the checkout.xml with my changes everything works fine.

Comment: The root of your problem is that your XML assigns the billing and shipping templates to the login template, which has no way of rendering them. If you look at `checkout/onepage.phtml` you can see it loops through the various checkout stages, you will need to rework this such that the login, billing and shipping templates are all handled as one stage. I'm sorry I don't have time to go into much more detail than that right now, but hopefully I've given enough of a starting point for you to figure out the rest. Best of luck!

Comment: I wrote an extension. In this I build my own onepage.phtml, login.phtml, billingphtml, shipping.phtml (own template) and the dedicated blocks. I change the steps of the checkout-process and everything works fine if I take the whole checkout.xml-code and make my changes like in the code above. So the changes of the child-blocks in the xml-file are not the problem because it works. I don't want to take the whole code because when updating magento mymodule_checkout.xml will not be updating. Magento don't combine checkout.xml with mymodule_checkout.xml.

Comment: Assuming a structure similar to `/app/code/local/[NAMESPACE]/[MODULENAME]`, what is your `namespace` and what is your `modulename`? The reason I ask is that in your `config.xml` for the module, `<layout><updates><checkout><file>mymodule_checkout.xml</file></checkout></updates></layout>` the tag `<checkout>` should be the same as your `modulename`. Failing that, what Magento version are you on and can you supply your entire config.xml and mymodule_checkout.xml to stackoverflow@wildworx.co.uk?

Comment: I have send you the current used files. The modulename is "checkout". The Magento Version is 1.6.2.0.